# How to find sum of recursion result

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

First write a function called `rec_dig_sum` that takes in an integer and returns the recursive digit sum of that number.

Examples of recursive digit sums:

```
101 => 1+0+1 = 2
191 => 1+9+1 = 11 => 1+1 = 2
5697 => 5+6+9+7 = 27 => 2+7 = 9
```

Then use that function within another function called `distr_of_rec_digit_sums`, that returns a dictionary where the keys are recursive digit sums, and the values are the counts of those digit sums occurring between a low and high (inclusive) range of input numbers. Assume low and high are positive integers where high is greater than low, and neither low nor high are negative.

I have this as the first part:

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
    total = 0
    for i in str(n):
      total += int(i)
    return total
```

Comment: For a recursive function to function as such you need two things at the minimum: the function must call itself and there should be a base case (limiting condition) to stop infinite recursion from occurring. You don't seem to have either of those implemented. Please check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/).

Comment: def rec_dig_sum(n): 
    ...:     total = 0 
    ...:     sub = 0 
    ...:     for i in str(n): 
    ...:       sub += int(i) 
    ...:     for i in str(sub): 
    ...:         total += int(i)   
    ...:     return total 
please check it, is it work or not.

Comment: This is the second part of the question:
 def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
    '''
    Returns a dictionary representing the counts
    of recursive digit sums within a given range.

    Parameters
    ----------
    low: int
        an integer, 0 or positive, representing
        the lowest value in the range of integers
        for which finding the recursive digit sum
    high: int
        a positive integer greater than low, the
        inclusive upper bound for which finding
        the recursive digit sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It bothers me that the OP's *recursive* solution, and the other solutions presented here, have a `for` loop in the middle of them!  Let's go *fully* (doubly) recursive on this problem! And since it's a *number* problem, let's also toss that `str()` function everyone else is using:

```
def rec_dig_sum(number):
    if number < 10:
        return number

    quotient, remainder = divmod(number, 10)

    return rec_dig_sum(rec_dig_sum(quotient) + remainder)

print(rec_dig_sum(101))
print(rec_dig_sum(191))
print(rec_dig_sum(5697))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
2
2
9
>
```

My example solution for the second function is conventional, but one of my few opportunites to use the `dict.fromkeys()` method:

```
def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
    histogram = dict.fromkeys(range(10), 0)

    for number in range(low, high + 1):  # a low and high (inclusive) range
        histogram[rec_dig_sum(number)] += 1

    return histogram

print(distr_of_rec_digit_sums(0, 1500))
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
{0: 1, 1: 167, 2: 167, 3: 167, 4: 167, 5: 167, 6: 167, 7: 166, 8: 166, 9: 166}
>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help. This finally helped with the solution I needed. I am new to python (less than 3 months), so would you mind explaining each function? I have not seen divmod before. 
Could I have used another word other than histogram in the second function?

Comment: @user13682040, the `divmod()` function does two types of division, `//` and `%`, at the same time.  You can do `help(divmod)` at the Python interpreter for more information.  In the second function, `histogram` is just a variable name, use whatever you want that's more informative.

Answer (score 1):

So for both parts of your question.

First, the recursive function:

```py
def recursive_digits(n):
    total = sum([int(i) for i in str(n)])
    if total < 10:
        return total
    else:
        return recursive_digits(total)
```

Then you use it in the other function:

```py
def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low, high):
    
    digits = {item : 0 for item in range(10)}
    for i in range(low, high+1):
        digits[recursive_digits(i)] += 1
    return digits
```

And since the function name starts with 'distr', I guess, someone is interested in the distribution in digit sums. It is surprisingly (or unsurprisingly) uniform. This is for the range in your question (0 - 1500).

[image]

Comment: so i am getting this:

Comment: AssertionError: 1500 != 10

Comment: Where do you use `assert`?

Comment: I am a couple of months into learning python, so I am not sure what that means. I did keep my part 1 code if that matters at all?

Comment: Try only my code and see if it works. It won't work with your code.

Comment: I still end up with the same answer.

Comment: I think I am supposed to end up with a single digit number, but the answer seems to want 10 like the assertion error indicates.

Comment: The code works perfectly for me. Do you use `assert` anywhere in the code? What version of Python do you use?

Comment: No, I have not inserted `assert` anywhere. I am training for a program so whatever they are using because it is one of their practice problems. I ran it in repl.it and I get numbers in the value position that are from anywhere in the single digits to almost 20. I guess somehow I am supposed to get 10 based on the assertion error?

Comment: @user13682040, can you please post the entire error message?

Comment: @user13682040, I'm sorry but you shouldn't be getting values greater than 10. The base condition in the recursive function **only** stops recursion if the value is *less than 10*. You can see in the graph I posted that I ran it for the range 0-1500 like in your question and all values were between 1-9.

Comment: FAIL: test (test_methods.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 14, in test
    self.assertEqual(len(sum_dict), 10)
AssertionError: 1500 != 10

Comment: @user13682040, misunderstood the second part of the question. See updated code in the answer. Should work now.

Comment: I am getting a Keyerror: 10 and its pointing to this line: digits[recursive_digits(i)] += 1

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. The error suggests that it's trying to access the item '10' in the dictionary and it's not finding one. But the result of `recursive_digits()` function can never be 10 or higher. It's specifically stated in the line: `if total < 10:`. Everything works fine when I run it. Would you be able to provide a link to the exercise you're trying to do if it's online?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to access the problem because it requires an account with the program. Ill keep looking at it tomorrow and be back on here with the solution.

Comment: Just try running my code in some normal Python editor and see if the result is what the question expects it to be. When I run it I get: `{0: 1, 1: 167, 2: 167, 3: 167, 4: 167, 5: 167, 6: 166, 7: 166, 8: 166, 9: 166}` - frequencies of each of different recursive sums for your range.

Comment: The OP's problem description mentions "inclusive upper bound" so you may need to change `range(low, high):` to `range(low, high + 1):` if I understand that correctly.

Comment: @cdlane, thanks! That's a good idea! I'll amend the code!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

#### Without recursion it will be:

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
  total = 0
  for i in str(n):
    total += int(i)
  return str(total)

t = "5697"
while len(t) != 1:
    t = rec_dig_sum(t)

print (t)
```

#### With recursion

We need a condition to break out of recursion, for this case we want to stop when the number of digits is 1 i.e we will break if `len(n) === 1`.

If not we calculate the current sum and and again start.

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
  if len(n) == 1:
    return int(n)

  total = 0
  for i in str(n):
    total += int(i)
  
  return rec_dig_sum(str(total))

rec_dig_sum(str(5697))
```

If you are learning recursion and facing difficulty, start by writing the same using loops (non-recursive) and then try to make it recursive by targeting to remove the loop.

Comment: So my issue is the second part of the question where I would have to use the rec_deg_sum function. With the number 5+6+9+7 = 27, the the second function should find 2+7 = 9 using the first function. The parameters are (low=0, high=1500), and I am not sure what that means

Comment: As far as I understand the question you need to run recursive function in a loop between values 0 and 1500 and for every run record in a dict what your original number was and what the sum of digits is.

Comment: The problem states, "takes in an integer" which your iterative solution does, but your recursive solution relies on taking in a *string* and will break otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a recursive solution would fit better, such as:

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise Exception('the arg must be positive')

    # Stop condition: single number
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        # Convert n into a str and each number back into int to be added
        total = sum(map(int, str(n)))
        return rec_dig_sum(total)
```